# algoritmo en psudocodigo mostrando unidades, decenas y centenas de número dentro de un rango

Tags: algoritmos, pseint, pseudocódigo

es un psudocódigo, el algoritmo tiene que leer un numero de 3 cifras y luego leer cada cifra por separado, pero el problema es que solo he logrado leer la ultima cifra, cuando intento leer las faltantes no lo hago correctamente y no se que debería hacer para lograrlo, les agradecería si me pueden explicar como puedo resolverlo usando cosas

```
CODIGO: 

Algoritmo ejercicio3
    Numero000
FinAlgoritmo

SubAlgoritmo Numero000
    a es entero  
    leer a 
    si (a<100)o(a>1000) entonces 
    escribir "Error, el numero debe ser de 3 cifras"
    sino 
    si (a>=100)y(a<1000) entonces 
    escribir "el numero de 3 cifras es: " , a; 
    FinSi
    finsi 
    escribir "las cifras del numero son: " 
    b<-a mod 10 
    escribir "ultima cifra: " , b ;


FinSubAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LA SOLUCION ES LA SIGUIENTE:**

Despues de validar la entrada y confirmar que el numero NO esta en el rango (a<100)o(a>999) entonces tomas el numero y lo conviertes en caracter para separarlo en subcadenas con el comando Subcadena(cadena, inicio, posicion) por cada segmento para unidad, decena y centena. Luego muestras el resultado de cada variable.

Aqui tienes el codigo:

```
Algoritmo ejercicio3

        Numero000
FinAlgoritmo

SubAlgoritmo Numero000
    // entrada
    Escribir  "Escriba un numero entre 100 a 999:"
    a es entero  
    num es caracter

    leer a 
    // validacion de entrada
    si (a<100)o(a>999) entonces 
        escribir "Error, el numero debe ser de 3 cifras"
    sino 
       // separar unidades
        num <-ConvertirATexto(a)
        unidad <- Subcadena(num,3,3)
        decena <-Subcadena(num,2,2)
        centena <- Subcadena(num,1,1)
        // salida
        Escribir num

        Escribir "Centena:" + centena
        Escribir "Decena:" + decena
        Escribir "Unidad:" + unidad

    finsi 

FinSubAlgoritmo
```

Esta es la salida del codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Algoritmo cifrasnumero

```
Definir num,nm,numc,c, numd,d,numu, l Como Entero
Escribir "Digite un numero de 4 cifras"
Repetir
    leer num 
Hasta Que num > 999 & num <10000
l= Longitud(ConvertirATexto(num))
Mientras l >=1 Hacer
    
    si l=4 Entonces
        nm = trunc(num/1000)
        l= l-1
    FinSi
    
    si l=3 Entonces
        numc =num-(nm*1000)
        c= trunc(numc/100)
        l= l-1
    FinSi
    
    si l=2 Entonces
        numd =numc-(c*100)
        d= trunc(numd/10)
        l= l-1
    FinSi
    
    si l=1 Entonces
        numu=numd-(d*10)
        l= l-1
    FinSi
FinMientras
Escribir "El numero ",num," tiene: "
Escribir nm, " unidades de mil"
Escribir c, " centenas"
Escribir d, " decenas"
Escribir numu, " unidades"
```

FinAlgoritmo

Answer (score 0):

Para leer un número de tres cifras y luego descomponerlo en sus cifras individuales, puedes seguir el siguiente enfoque en tu pseudocódigo. Vamos a utilizar la división y el módulo para separar las cifras del número.

Primero, te muestro cómo corregir y completar tu pseudocódigo:

```
Algoritmo ejercicio3
    Numero000
FinAlgoritmo

SubAlgoritmo Numero000
    a es entero  
    leer a 
    si (a < 100) o (a >= 1000) entonces 
        escribir "Error, el numero debe ser de 3 cifras"
    sino 
        escribir "El numero de 3 cifras es: ", a
        // Descomponiendo el número en sus cifras
        c <- a div 100 // Primera cifra
        b <- (a mod 100) div 10 // Segunda cifra
        d <- a mod 10 // Tercera cifra (última)
        escribir "Las cifras del numero son: ", c, ", ", b, ", ", d
    fin si 
FinSubAlgoritmo
```

En este pseudocódigo, la variable a es el número de tres cifras que ingresa el usuario. Luego se verifica si a está en el rango de 100 a 999 (ambos incluidos, que son los números de tres cifras). Si a es válido, entonces se procede a descomponerlo:

c <- a div 100 obtiene la primera cifra del número al dividir a entre 100.
b <- (a mod 100) div 10 obtiene la segunda cifra. Primero, a mod 100 elimina la primera cifra (dejando solo las dos últimas cifras), y luego la división por 10 deja la segunda cifra.
d <- a mod 10 obtiene la tercera y última cifra del número.
Este enfoque asegura que puedas leer e imprimir cada una de las tres cifras del número introducido por el usuario.